# Filter Emojis like \\xe2\\x80\\x9e from HTML in python 3

Tags: python, html, unicode, emoji

So I'm working on a project where I need to manually filter a HTML of social media comment threads with split and replace and re.sub and that stuff, I wouldn't get the information required otherwise (BeautifulSoup filters out important information too). In the end, I'm left with something like this:

Best of luck to you now that there's some real competition \xf0\x9f\x98\x8f

Thanks \xf0\x9f\x98\x82

I searched for any way to get rid of these or replace them with actual emojis, but I found nothing. I did find commands that filter out emojis when they look like this U+1F600 or like this :cowboy hat face: or like this \U0001F606, and I did find someone who filtered things like this \xe2\x80\x99, but he only did it for semicolons and quotation marks, not emojis. I also couldn't find a way to use encode and decode for this.

Short: I want "Thanks \xf0\x9f\x98\x82" to become "Thanks".

So I'm new to working with websites and maybe the answer is quite simple, but as I said, I found nothing on this on the internet. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

if you only want ascii characters in your text , you can enode and decode the text with ascii

```
text = """Best of luck to you now that there's some real competition \xf0\x9f\x98\x8f
Thanks \xf0\x9f\x98\x82"""

text = text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()

>>> text

Best of luck to you now that there's some real competition 
Thanks
```

Comment: First off, thanks a lot, it did help me. However, while it works in the shell with the exact same strings, it doesn't work in my program. Because I don't want to share all 200 lines of worst code imaginable full of depressed german comments with you, I'll have to figure out the rest on my own.